# How to force pd.ExcelWriter to check if file exists, and if does not exist create new file?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am using `ExcelWriter` in pandas to write dataframes to different tabs on the spreadsheet like so:

```
import pandas as pd

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('/path/to/file/excel_test.xlsx')


df.to_excel(writer,'tab1')
df.to_excel(writer, 'tab2')

writer.save()
```

This code only work if the file `excel_test.xlsx` exists.

How can I force `ExcelWriter` to check if the file exists and if it does not exist create a new file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
import os
exists = os.path.isfile('/path/to/file')
if not exists:
    # write file
```